# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and swipe actions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view. Every cell update every 10 seconds. And each cell has editActions like:

[image]

But when i swipe left to see actions, and in the same time reloadRowsAtIndexPaths function was called, it close this actions. Is there a way to just update values in cell and not close actions ?

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            case .Delete:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            case .Update:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            default:
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: which library are you using for those actions?

Answer (score 0):

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` will definitely reset the state of the cell. One way to overcome that is :

1. Just before you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` check whether the actions are revealed or not, and store it in a `BOOL`. The library you used for the actions reveal will most probably have a method to check its status.
2. Programmatically restore the state of the actions reveal just after reload.

Comment: > Just before you call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: check whether the actions are revealed or not, and store it in a BOOL
this is the problem... i can't find this method

Comment: which library are you using for the actions reveal??

Comment: standard tableView method to create actions: ```func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ```and ```NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate``` for delegate items in database